Hosting dotnet core 8 app in AWS but doing authorization to backend via MSAL SSO in Angular 18
Is it possible to host dotnet core 8 app in AWS but to do authentication and authorization to backend via MSAL SSO Angular 18? AWS is going to be used only to host the code. But we want to do login functionality via Azure Entra ID. Backend is DotNet Core 8, frontend Angular 18.
